# SharePoint Online: Invitation in Finnish language

Tags: sharepoint-online, language, external-users

My colleague sent an invitation to SharePoint Online website to german external users. It is commnon that invitations are send in English, but this one was sent in Finnish language. My question is how is it possible? What determines the language in which invitation is sent? (I tried to test invitations with changing language on sender and receiver PC with Win10, but nothing was solved. Invitations were still in English).

The finnish invitation you can see below. Thank You for any help!

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I have a similar issue, but invitations to external users are sent in Dutch instead of English. Invitations to internal users are correct, in English. Sender's regional and language settings are all English. Sender is on Citrix XenDesktop, so signs in via ADFS. Are you using XenDesktop too?

Answer (score 1):

Found this on O365 Service Health dashboard. Seems to be known issue

> Title: Sharing invitation messages sent using the wrong language
>
> User Impact: New external users may receive sharing invites from
>   SharePoint Online or OneDrive for Business in the wrong language.
>
> More info: This issue is intermittent in nature, and appears to only
>   affect a small subset of the share invite messages that are
>   automatically generated when a site is shared to new external users.
>   Users that have received share invites previously do not appear to be
>   affected.
>
> Current status: Our investigation determined that there was a recent
>   change in localization behavior, possibly related to an update
>   intended to improve localization across the service. While we continue
>   our analysis of the root cause, we've collected enough data to start
>   formulating a fix which should resolve the issue. We anticipate that
>   we'll be ready to start testing the fix within the next two days, and
>   if the results are positive, we'll then roll the fix out broadly. By
>   Friday, March 24, 2017, we expect to have the fix deployed broadly
>   enough to verify whether it resolves the underlying problem.
>
> Scope of impact: A few customers have reported this issue, and our
>   analysis indicates that this issue could potentially affect any
>   sharing invite message sent to external users by the SharePoint Online
>   or OneDrive for Business services.

Answer (score 0):

What is the default language of the site collection where the site resides? Or the tenant's root site collection?

I had issue where the SharePoint home (sharepoint.aspx) was in wrong language, Finnish in fact :). After a while I found out that the root site collection which was not used for much anything had language set to Finnish.